# cakephp multiple insert from a form

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-model

I have a site in cakephp 2.2, and I have a form with many input type text with a value taken from a query.

I want when I save with a submit button to create for every input text a new record into my table in my database.

First of all I have make a query a simple find and put it into a variable(prop). I make a `foreach` and for every record that I have found I create an input text. But when I save I don't want to update but to create a new record into my table the value can be changed or not but I want to save each  input type. I have try something but create only one record with value of the last input text and not for all.

My table have some field

- table name: `ingredient_properties`
- model name: `IngredientProperty`
- field: `id`, `ingredient_id`, `property_id`, `user_id`, `created`, `modified`.

This is my view *add_prop.ctp*

```
echo $this->Form->create('Ingredient', array ('class' => 'form')); 
    echo'<p>ELENCO PROPRIETA\'</p>';
    foreach($prop as $p){ 
        echo('<p>'.$p['Property']['PropertyAlias'][0]['alias']);
        echo $this->Form->input('IngredientProperty.ingredient_id', array ('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>  $p['IngredientProperty']['ingredient_id'],'label'=> false, 'id' => 'id'));
        echo $this->Form->input('IngredientProperty.property_id', array ('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>  $p['IngredientProperty']['property_id'],'label'=> false, 'id' => 'id'));
        echo $this->Form->input('IngredientProperty.value', array ('label'=> false, 'id' => 'value_'.$p['IngredientProperty']['id'], 'name' => 'value_'.$p['IngredientProperty']['id'],'value'=> $p['IngredientProperty']['value'], 'after' => '<div class="message">Inserisci un valore</div>'));
        echo('</p>');
}
echo $this->Form->submit('Salva', array('id'=>'add_prop'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

And this is my controller Ingredient.php (`Ingredient` has many `IngredientProperty` and `Property` has many `ingredientProperty`)

```
public function add_prop($alias) {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            //SAVE
            if ($this->Ingredient->IngredientProperty->saveAll($this->request->data)){
                $this->set('flash_element','success');
                $this->Session->setFlash ('Proprietà aggiornate con successo.');
                //$this->redirect(array('action'=>'photo',$alias));
            }
            else{
                $this->set('flash_element','error');
                $this->Session->setFlash('Errore di salvataggio proprietà');
            }
        }   
        else{
            //QUERY TO RETRIEVE DATA

            $this->set('prop',$this->Ingredient->IngredientProperty->find('all', array('recursive' => 2,
                        'conditions' => array('IngredientProperty.ingredient_id' => $id))));

            $this->loadModel('Property');
            $this->set('prop_all',$this->Property->find('all'));

            $this->loadModel('Unit');
            $this->set('unit',$this->Unit->find('all'));

        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is or what we can help with. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I make a query and for every record I print an input text in a form and whe I save I want to create for every field a record with the new value, for each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code and ask if it not worked for you.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Ingredient', array ('class' => 'form')); 
echo'<p>ELENCO PROPRIETA\'</p>';
foreach($prop as $p){ 
    echo('<p>'.$p['Property']['PropertyAlias'][0]['alias']);
    echo $this->Form->input('IngredientProperty.ingredient_id][', array ('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>  $p['IngredientProperty']['ingredient_id'],'label'=> false, 'id' => 'id'));
    echo $this->Form->input('IngredientProperty.property_id][', array ('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>  $p['IngredientProperty']['property_id'],'label'=> false, 'id' => 'id'));
    echo $this->Form->input('IngredientProperty.value][', array ('label'=> false, 'id' => 'value_'.$p['IngredientProperty']['id'], 'name' => 'value_'.$p['IngredientProperty']['id'],'value'=> $p['IngredientProperty']['value'], 'after' => '<div class="message">Inserisci un valore</div>'));
    echo('</p>');
}
echo $this->Form->submit('Salva', array('id'=>'add_prop'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

And check the form requested data into your controller via:

```
pr($this->request->data);
die;
```